# Ordering of UI controls JS, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have couple of input controls to capture text in the UI, called 'First Name' and 'Last Name'. Want to order these controls in accordance with locale. For example, if locale is en, first name should follow last name. Else if locale is ja, last name should follow first name.

The only solution that I can think of is a conditional statement.

I have done bit google, explored react-intl as well, but didn't help much. Is there a better way to handle ordering of controls in accordance with locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need an object that represents your data:

```
const fields = [
  {key: 'firstName', en: 'First Name', fr: 'Prenom'},
  {key: 'lastName', en: 'Last Name', fr: 'Nom'}
];
```

then you can sort it whichever way you like:

```
const locale = 'fr'; // Can be anything here, based on your config
const sortedFields = fields.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a[locale] > b[locale]) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (a[locale] < b[locale]) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
});
```

once your fields are sorted, you can render your components:

```
render() {
  return <div>
    {sortedFields.map(f => <span>{f.key}</span>)}
  </div>;
}
```